# How to install in python 3.4 - .whl files

Tags: python, numpy, module

I recently tried to re-install numpy for python 3.4, since I got a new computer, and am struggling. I am on windows 8.1, and from what I remember I previously used a .exe file that did everything for me. However, this time I was given a .whl file (apparently this is a "Wheel" file), which I cannot figure out how to install.

Other posts have explained that I have to use PIP, however the explanations of how to install these files that I have been able to find are dreadful. The command "python install pip" or "pip install numpy" or all the other various commands I have seen only return an error that "python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file", or "pip is not recognised as an internal...." ect.

I have also tried "python3.4", "python.exe" and many others since it does not like python. The file name of the numpy file that I downloaded is "numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl".

So can anybody give me a **Detailed** tutorial of how to use these, as by the looks of things all modules are using these now. Also, why did people stop using .exe files to install these? It was so much easier!

Comment: Make sure the python directory and its scripts directory are on your path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3.4 comes with PIP already included in the package, so you should be able to start using PIP immediately after installing Python 3.4. Commands like `pip install <packagename>` only work if the path to PIP is included in your `path` environment variable. If it's not, and you'd rather not edit your environment variables, you need to provide the full path. The default location for PIP in Python 3.4 is in `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.4.exe`. If that file exists there (it should), enter the command `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.4.exe install <numpy_whl_path>`, where `<numpy_whl_path>` is the full path to your numpy .whl file. For example: `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.4.exe install C:\Users\mwinfield\Downloads\numpy‑1.9.2+mkl‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I also found that the folders for python were messed up and I had to fix those.

Answer (score 8):

See the easiest solution is to unzip the `.whl` file using 7-zip. Then in the unzipped directory you will find the module which you can copy and paste in the directory `C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/` (or wherever else you have installed Python).

Comment: Thanks, this is a great alternative to the other solution. Personally I prefer using PIP once I got it working, but some others may prefer this way.

Comment: Could not get the pip to work but this worked great - much easier on a windows platform to just add the numpy module to the directory.