# How to install .whl files in python 3.4 from www.lfd.uci.edu

Tags: python

I tried to install pygame 3.4 from www.lfd.uci.edu
I read someone that told me to do this `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.4.exe` install `C:\Users\tomer2\Desktop\pygame+mkl‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl`

but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: You can't install `pygame` by passing the name of the `numpy` .whl file. Think about what you are doing next time you blindly run a command found on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The code you tried seems suspiciously similar to the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284282/how-to-install-in-python-3-4-whl-files/29286276#29286276). That command is not a magical string that does everything: it won't install `pygame` for you when you give it the name of a `numpy` .whl file. For this to work, you have to download the proper file, then use a command that includes the proper filename.

Comment: i am sorry when i post it i copyed the wrong text, but when i used it i got an error