# How to install python modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyhook

I am new at python programing language, I want to install .whl file with pip but it doesn`t happen... I am trying to download pyHook for 64-bit windows 7 for python 3.6 or 2.7.

Please help me!

Comment: You can find more in here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file

Comment: The phrase "it doesn't happen" isn't very useful. Please edit your question to show the command that you tried and the response from `pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909082/3521116), you simply have to use pip command to install whl file as well, 
`pip install some-package.whl` assuming .whl file is in the same directory you are running command from, if not just provide the complete path like
`pip install C:\somedir\mypackage.whl`

**Method 2**

Alternatively you can unzip the `.whl` file using 7-zip. Then in the unzipped directory you will find the module which you can copy and paste in the directory C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/ (or wherever else you have installed Python). as already anwered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33483629/3521116)

> This method only works if there is not extension module to be compiled, therefore in this case it won't work as pointed out by @roland-smith

Comment: This particular package contains an extension module that needs to be compiled. So method 2 won't work.

Comment: thanks for the input, I will edit my answer accordingly